# Postgres and Laravel search query

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a query for multiple searches, the problem is with one of them, I get a correct result from it, but in combination with the rest, I get the wrong response for the rest of the fields.

```
//I get the correct result for first if, but the second one returns a wrong response.
        if ($request->has('search_fullname') && !is_null($request->search_fullname)) {
            $query->where('full_name', 'ILIKE', $request->search_fullname . '%')
                ->orWhere('full_name', 'ILIKE', '% ' . $request->search_fullname . '%');
        }

        if ($request->has('search_gender') && !is_null($request->search_gender)) {
            $query->where('gender', '=', $request->search_gender);
        } //like this if I have many more, the problem is strict from the first one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you apply `where(A)->orWhere(B)` to query and apply new `where(C)...` method, it will become:

```sql
where (A and C and D ...) or B
```

you need to change it to

```sql
where (A or B) and C and D ....
```

so the first query need to be like this:

```php
if ($request->has('search_fullname') && !is_null($request->search_fullname)) {
    $query->where(function($q) {
          $q->where('full_name', 'ILIKE', $request->search_fullname . '%')
            ->orWhere('full_name', 'ILIKE', '% ' . $request->search_fullname . '%');
    })       
}
```

Secondly, you can use [when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses) as condition method, it will apply to a query only when the request field is not empty.

```php
$query->when($request->input('search_fullname'), function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('full_name', 'ILIKE', $request->search_fullname.'%')
          ->orWhere('full_name', 'ILIKE', '% ' . $request->search_fullname . '%');
    });   
})->when($request->input('search_gender'), function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('gender', '=', $request->search_gender);
});
```